# In Mongo, how do I pretty-print results so .find() looks like .findOne()

Tags: mongodb, database

`findOne()` results in pretty-print json object.

`find()` results in jarbled json object.

How can I make `find()` the same as `findOne()`, when it comes to display in the mongo shell?

Comment: What about `find().limit(1)` ?

Comment: my mongo shell does nothing when I run a 'find()', I don't get any errors, nor do I get results but when I pull data from python or php I get my results... isn't this weird?

Answer (score 163):

If you are scripting using javascript, you can use dcrosta's answer.
But if you want to pretty print directly on the mongo interactive shell, you have to append pretty() to your find() queries.

Type on the shell:
`db.yourcollection.find().pretty()`

Comment: This seems to have the advantage of maintaining the normal limit for find() too. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Almost too intuitive. I googled "mongo console pretty output". Who knew it's just .pretty()

Comment: Is there any way to make .pretty() the default?

Comment: The Casbah API (Scala) does not seem to have .pretty or am I missing something?

Comment: To Jonathan Dumaine, your question has been answered by David Weinraub later in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/48438882/2714285

Answer (score 21):

The cursor object returned by `find()` supports `forEach()`, so you can use:

```
db.foo.find().forEach(printjson)
```

However note that, unlike the default output of `find()` which shows the first 10 objects then lets you choose whether to continue iterating or not, `forEach()` will iterate the entire result set. Thus if your query returns many results, this may take a while and may not be terribly helpful. `limit()` is your friend here.

Comment: In Mongo 2.0 this is superceded by the .pretty() answer by Rohan.

Answer (score 6):

It may not have been available at the time the question was asked, but to make the default output for all `find()` queries to be pretty, I use:

```
DBQuery.prototype._prettyShell = true
```

I also add the following:

```
DBQuery.prototype.ugly = function() {
    this._prettyShell = false;
    return this;
}
```

which enables me to uglify the results of a single `find()` query using:

```
db.mycollection.find().ugly()
```

I typically add both prototype declarations into my `~/.mongorc.js` file so they are available in all mongo cli shells.

Answer (score 5):

The correct answer is already provided with the use of `.pretty()`.

However just as a side note, you can also call .toArray() on the cursor to get the documents as javascript array of JSON.

```
db.foo.find().toArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

The handy mongo-shell enhancer **mongo-hacker** (http://mongodb-tools.com/tool/mongo-hacker/) will allow you to do that and more fancy things.

- Developper site : http://tylerbrock.github.io/mongo-hacker/
- Github repos : https://github.com/TylerBrock/mongo-hacker